# Newbie question - which css file to edit

Tags: customization, css

Hi I am currently using the Phlox theme to create a website but there are a few tweaks I'l like to make the CSS typography but as there are multiple CSS files, I'm not sure which one I should be digging into to edit?
There is `Base.css` or `Main.css` and they both look very similar.

I know I can adjust a lot of the font attributes within the theme GUI but there are a few little extras I'd like to add like `line-height` and changing to use *rem* instead of *px*.

Answer (score 0):

You generally shouldn't edit your theme's CSS files if the theme isn't one you authored yourself. The reason is that these changes would be lost if you ever updated the theme.

The two recommended ways of adding CSS of your own are:

1. Go to *Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS* and add your CSS here. This CSS is output in a `<style>` tag on the front end.
2. Create a child theme. This is a bit more complicated, but the process is documented [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/). This will give you your own theme with its own CSS file that you can safely edit, while continuing to load the parent theme's styles. The only problem is that different themes often work differently and there can be quirks for creating child themes for them. You should consult your theme's documentation to see if there's any information on creating child themes, or even a sample child theme that you can use. If not, and the process documented at the link I gave earlier doesn't work as expected, you should contact the theme author for support.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob  There is a child theme with it so I'll try making the changes to that instead and see how I go.

Comment: Keep in mind that if you didn’t author the child theme either then the risks regarding updates still apply. Child themes are only safe to edit if they will not receive updates.